# Forcer refresh on DNSNameResolver

Tags: grpc, grpc-java

We're using `ManagedChannel`, and at some point we need to have a `DNSResolution` refresh to get new pods on the cluster.

so far we try to use `max_connection_age_grace_ms` and we can see GO_AWAY calls from server but client did not receive this since we have `isito side-car` in front of him.

Our next idea was try to force the `refresh`  invoking.

https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/core/src/main/java/io/grpc/internal/DnsNameResolver.java#L210

Any idea what is the standard way to do it now without have to implement our own `DnsNameResolver`

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the server the client connects to to manage the connection lifetime. So in this case, you want to configure the proxies with Istio.

This is possible using [EnvoyFilter](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/envoy-filter/). The first example in its documentation adjusts http_connection_manager to set [`idle_timeout`](https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/blob/1fd0b996f820ef5a85b0889c7937e82696c95f83/api/envoy/config/core/v3/protocol.proto#L229). The same approach would work to set [`max_connection_duration`](https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/blob/1fd0b996f820ef5a85b0889c7937e82696c95f83/api/envoy/config/core/v3/protocol.proto#L237):

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: EnvoyFilter
metadata:
  name: hcm-connection-duration
  namespace: srv-namespace
spec:
  workloadSelector:
    labels:
      app: myapp
  configPatches:
  - applyTo: NETWORK_FILTER
    match:
      context: SIDECAR_INBOUND
      listener:
        filterChain:
          filter:
            name: "envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager"
    patch:
      operation: MERGE
      value:
        name: "envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager"
        typed_config:
          "@type": "type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.network.http_connection_manager.v3.HttpConnectionManager"
          common_http_protocol_options:
            max_connection_duration: 300s
```